# Build issue in android

Tags: quickblox, quickblox-android

***BaseDialogActivity***

> error: cannot access Player
>
> class file for com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player not found

***BaseDialogActivity***

> error: cannot access Player class file for
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player not found

Comment: Please, post detailed question.

Comment: @RajneeshShukla
just download
https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android
and make build then show me error 
error: cannot access Player class file for com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player not found